# HTML tag <img> referencing image in directories doesn't work

Tags: html

I'm trying to display an image with the  tag and referencing an image in subfolders, but it doesn't work, it only works when the image is in the same folder as the script file.

Here is my code:

```
<img src = "SubFolder\SubSubFolder\plant.png"/>
```

Comment: Forward slashes may help /

Comment: and make sure the path relative to current position is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<img src="SubFolder/SubSubFolder/plant.png" />`

HTML uses forward slashes (`/`), not backwards ones (`\`).

If this doesn't work, it would also benefit to check that the image at `SubFolder/SubSubFolder/plant.png` actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="your path here " alt="alter text " height="42" width="42">
```

this will help and make sure the path should not have space 
one more thing that whether file is in same folder or not start giving path from root `/mainfolder/sup/../file.png`  that would always work